# Twilio A2P 10DLC registration. How to register campaign for random messages?

Tags: twilio

In our application we assign these 10DLC number to our users. Users communicate with their customers using these numbers. As their conversations can be random and and can send any text as they are sent by real person, how can we register campaign for it as campaign needs message template to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [list of Standard Campaign Use Cases](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260801844470-List-of-campaign-use-case-types-for-A2P-10DLC-registration). I'd recommend reading each description to see what best matches your customer's use case.

What type of random conversations are they?

- Does it sound like a `Customer Care` use case? -- Used for support, account management, and other avenues of customer interaction
- How about a `Mixed` use case -- Used to cover multiple use cases but will have lower throughput and higher costs?

What is the volume of messages you're needing? There is a `Low-Volume` use case similar to the `Mixed` use case, but it has the lowest throughput.

Finally, check out the [`Special Campaign`](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402972441243-Special-Use-Cases-for-A2P-10DLC) use cases to see if those are more in line. For instance, is it a `Social` use case that is used between public figures/influences and their communities?